# GitLab port 2222

Tags: git, gitlab

I cannot clone repository, which i have permissions to, using port 2222.
When i try to clone using
 `git clone git@<address>:2222/<user>/<repo>.git`,
i get this:

```
Cloning into '<repo_name>'...
remote:
remote: ========================================================================
remote:
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
remote:
remote: ========================================================================
remote:
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check first who GitLab think you are with:

```
ssh -Tv git@<address>:2222
```

You should receive a `Welcome to GitLab, @username!` message.

If `@username` is not a user added as collaborator to the project, that would explain the error message.

Or, if you do not see a welcome message, double-check "[Use SSH keys to communicate with GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html)" and make sure your SSH public key is registered to the proper user SSH setting page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was problem on owner's side. He didnt give me full permissions needed. It's resolved. Sorry for bothering :)

Comment: So this is as I mentioned in my answer? ("If @username is not a user added as collaborator to the project, that would explain the error message.")